# Sphinx search error: query too complex, not enough stack

Tags: php, macos, sphinx

I am trying to setup Sphinx search in my Mac.

I have done complete installation and also indexed the tables. If I tried to use search I am getting following error.

```
index 'jokes': search error: query too complex, not enough stack (thread_stack=197908K or higher required).
```

I searched google for thread_stack and increased its size , but no luck. I restarted sphinx many times.

Below is my Config file.

```
source src1
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = root
    sql_db          = searchj_jokes
    sql_port        = 3307
    sql_query       = SELECT entry_id, entry, picture_url,tags,date_added FROM jokes
}

index jokes
{
    source          = src1
    path            = indexes/jokes
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = none
    min_word_len        = 1
    charset_type        = utf-8
    html_strip      = 0
}


source tags
{
        type                    = mysql
        sql_host                = localhost
        sql_user                = root
        sql_pass                = root
        sql_db                  = searchj_jokes
        sql_port                = 3307
        sql_field_string        = tag
        sql_query               = SELECT tag_id,tag FROM tags
}

index tagsIndex
{
        source                  = tags
        path                    = indexes/tagsIndex
        docinfo                 = extern
        mlock                   = 0
        morphology              = none
        min_word_len            = 1
        charset_type            = utf-8
        html_strip              = 0
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 32M
}

searchd
{
    listen          = 3307
    log             = log/searchd.log
    query_log       = log/query.log
    pid_file        = log/searchd.pid   
    thread_stack    = 8M
}
```

I can't see any error in log too. If any one can help me to guess what might be the error, it will be help full.

Comment: Did you try setting thread_stack to over 200M as suggested in the error message. Suggests you running a very complex query, can you simplify?

Comment: HI @barryhunter : Thanks for response. I tries that , but I got an error saying its higher than allowed limit. I think 8M is the max we can keep , also the query is not complex at all. Same setup and query is running fine in Linux (problem was with mac). Should I reinstall ?

Comment: What is an example query you running?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Mac OS X Mavericks. My database consists of 10,000 rows: each has a column for simple int id, and a mediumtext column with the full text of a magazine. A simple search for something like "bbs" results in "search error: query too complex, not enough stack (thread_stack=338033K or higher required)"

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer in the end.

Share here:

Just modify sphinx.conf and change

`sql_query_info         = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$id`

into

`#sql_query_info         = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$id`

And then restart you searchd.

Answer (score 1):

I was [advised at sphinxsearch.com](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11889) to avoid both the command-line search tool and the API. Instead they recommended I use SphinxQL. The following worked for me, and may work for you, too.

1. Launch searchd
2. From the command line, issue a query like this:

   ```
   mysql -h0 -P9306 -e "select * from jokes where match('chicken cross road'); show meta;"
   ```